# JavaScript Calendar odd behavior

Tags: javascript

I saw that there were other JS Calendars about but I wanted to try my hand at it and see if I can do it myself.  I ran into a bit of a snag.  Seems that when I run my script to generate this month's (August) calendar I am getting 29 days instead of 31.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and point me in the right direction please?

```
var arrMonth = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
var arrWeek = new Array("Su", "M", "Tu", "W", "Th", "F", "Sa");

var now = new Date();
var thisYear = now.getFullYear();
var thisMonth = now.getMonth();
var thisDate = now.getDate();
var thisDay = now.getDay();



var firstMonth = new Date();
var tempYear = firstMonth.setYear(thisYear);
var tempMonth = firstMonth.setMonth(thisMonth);
var tempDate = firstMonth.setDate(1);

var firstDay = firstMonth.getDay();
var totalDays = numberOfDays(thisYear, thisMonth);

var dayCounter = 1;
var strHTML = "";

strHTML += "<table border='1'>";
strHTML += "<tr>";
for(var x=0; x<arrMonth.length; x++){
    if(x == thisMonth){
        strHTML += "<td colspan='7' align='center'>" + arrMonth[x] + "</td>";
    }
}
strHTML += "</tr>";

strHTML += "<tr>";
for(var x=0; x<arrWeek.length; x++){
    strHTML += "<td align='center'>" + arrWeek[x] + "</td>";    
}
strHTML += "</tr>";

strHTML += "<tr>";
for(var x=0; x<40; x++){
    if(x < firstDay){
        strHTML += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }
    else if(x == firstDay){
        strHTML += "<td align='center'>" + dayCounter + "</td>";
        dayCounter++;
    }
    else{
        if(x <= totalDays){
            if((x % 7) == 0){
                strHTML += "</tr>";
                strHTML += "<tr>";
                strHTML += "<td align='center'>" + dayCounter + "</td>";
            }
            else{
                strHTML += "<td align='center'>" + dayCounter + "</td>";
            }
            dayCounter++;
        }
    }
}
alert(dayCounter + " : " + totalDays);
strHTML += "</tr>";
strHTML += "</table>";

alert(strHTML);

function numberOfDays(year, month) { 
    var d = new Date(year, month, 0); 
    return d.getDate(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `x` as a counter for the number of cells in the calendar, but compare it against the number of days in the month. That is, change this row:

```
if(x <= totalDays){
```

into this:

```
if( x < totalDays + firstDay ) {
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j9rtm/

Comment: Thanks Juhana, I'm not seeing how it worked but it worked.  How does adding firstDay change anything?

Comment: Remember that because `x` counts the *number of cells printed*, it's not comparable to `totalDays` which counts *number of dates* that should be printed. `x` includes the empty cells in the beginning of the calendar, you have to take them into account. Note that `x < totalDays + firstday` is the same as `x - firstDay < totalDays` (`x` with the empty cells removed). Take a look at this version which is exactly the same as yours except that we print `x` instead of `dayCounter`: http://jsfiddle.net/j9rtm/1/